# How can I use Html.ActionLink to specify an exact URL with MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following route:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Power", // Route name
            "Power/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new 
            { 
                controller = "flood", 
                action = "index", 
                id = UrlParameter.Optional 
            }
        );
```

and the following address which I call:

```
<a href="/Power/"  >
```

Now I would like to do the above call with an Html.ActionLink like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("xxx", 
                "index",
                "flood",
                new { "Power" },
                null 
                )
```

It seems not to work as I get an error "Invalid anonymous type declaration" where I have new { "Power" }. Can someone give me some advice and get me on the correct track.

I would also like to be able to call the following with another link:

```
<a href="/Power/001"  >`
```

thanks

ps. Please note I am using MVC3. I understand the syntax for this changed from version 1 > 2 > MVC3.

Answer (score 6):

Use a [RouteLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493103.aspx) instead of an [ActionLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493066.aspx):

```
@Html.RouteLink("xxx", "Power", new { id = "123" })
```

or if you specify the controller and the action with ActionLink and based on your route definition order the proper route should be picked:

```
@Html.ActionLink("xxx", "index", "flood", new { id = "123" }, null)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on the declaration of your parameters.
This will work fine:

Without ID:

```
@Html.ActionLink("xxx", 
            "index",
            "flood")
```

With ID:

```
@Html.ActionLink("xxx", 
            "index",
            "flood",
            new { id =123 },
            null 
            )
```

You're declaring a anonymous type, without saying the name of the property, only the value.

Comment: Why `id="Power"`? That's the name of the route.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your Question, take a look at my Edit.